# Making a partition bootable

Tags: installation, partitioning, gparted, testdisk

I used testdisk to recover my partitions after a long list of poor decisions and mishaps.

Now when I rebuilt my partitions, I was unable to select one of the partitions as bootable (*). I was forced to choose all my partitions as Primary (P). Now I have a windows partition which I want to make bootable.

I played around in the Windows command prompt with my limited knowledge and tried to make the windows os partition active. The error returned was "not a fixed mbr partition" or something like that.

What should I do? Should I try to deep search with testdisk again or try something with Gparted. I want to avoid the former option because it takes hours to finish a deep search.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your partition. You can do this by clicking -(minus) icon.

Then, add your partition You can do this by clicking +(plus) icon. and re size it so that you can leave certain space for making one partition into bootable and another for primary.

Comment: Wouldn't that wipe out my OS which is on that partition?

Comment: Yes it will wipe out your OS. If you don't want your OS to be deleted then just install it.

Answer (score 0):

Save your windows partition to a USB or seperate file, use a tool ( I use standard DiskBurn  ) and make the partions in a boot log ( ISO bootable format is usually name of execution ) and then save the bootable ISO in a random file, and then open Floppy Burner and select the ISO and burn it to your USB, wipe your current partitions and then boot computer on USB. After you boot get a recovery tool ( I recomend windows boot recovery tool v.1.0.2 ) find your old partitions ( to keep your data/apps if any were lost, r
Right click the found partitions, click save and open it will automatically exicuted the partions back on computer ( keep your windows partitions )